# drf. create serializer which creates and returns the field of the object being created in different ways

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

In drf i want create serializer that creates field "answerer" as number, but return it in the form of user object ({id, username})

```
class InitiateDialogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    initiator = ListUserViewSerializer(read_only=True)

    # -----> answerer = MaybeSomeDeusExMachinaSerializer()  <------
    # when creating Dialog i want pass only id of user
    # But when serializer returns created Dialog i want get in this field serialized user

    class Meta:
        model = Dialog
        fields = ('answerer', 'id', 'initiator')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'initiator')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['initiator'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just override "to_representation"
, but  maybe that not the best solution

```
class InitiateDialogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    initiator = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Dialog
        fields = ('answerer', 'id', 'initiator')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'initiator')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            validated_data['initiator'] = self.context['request'].user
            return super().create(validated_data)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            message = e.args[0]
            if 'UNIQUE constraint' in message:
                raise NotAcceptable('Диалог уже был создан')

    def to_representation(self, instance):  # <---
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['answerer'] = UserSerializer(User.objects.get(id=representation['answerer'])).data

        return representation
```

Comment: I hope somebody will offer better solution...